# ¿Cómo mostrar una vista sin el layout de la aplicación?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vistas

¿Cómo se hace para mostrar una Vista (view) de Rails sin mostrar el layout de la aplicación para un usuario registrado y otro layout para un visitante? ¿Se puede?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow quizas quiera echar un vistazo a esta pagina http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Podes cambiar el layout para un controlador o una acción del controlador, una manera de mostrar una vista con otro layout cuando el usuario no esta registrado seria así:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def my_action
    if current_user.nil?
      render layout: "new_user_layout"
    else
      render layout: "member_layout"
    end
  end

end
```

Para cambiar el layout de todos los controladores que heredan de ApplicationController seria lo siguiente:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :users_layout

  private
    def users_layout
      current_user.nil? ? "new_user_layout" : "member_layout"
    end

end
```

En las [guias de rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) podes encontrar más información sobre layouts.

Comment: Muy buena. Al final lo resolví:
  def new
    @registration = Registration.new
    render layout: "sin_menu" unless user_signed_in? 
  end

Comment: la respuesta de Gabriel es la más correcta para tu caso (usar 2 layouts distintos para distintas partes); pero si de verdad necesitás renderear *sin ningún layout*, lo que buscás es `layout: false` (no `nil`)

Answer (score 0):

este codigo es sino te gustaria usar ningun layout

```
 class MyController < ApplicationController

      def my_action
        #solo debes poner en modo false para  que lo desabilites solo para este metodo
         render layout: false
      end

    end
```

o tmb puede ser

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
layout: false
  def my_action

  end

end
```